# Integration of Infopath web forms with outlook mail

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, infopath

Hello is it possible to integrate Infopath web form with outlook mail when the user click a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can integrate it with Outlook directly, you would have to configure the Infopath form to send an email via an smtp server.